# Verifying a string length in an if statement. PHP

Tags: php, string, forms

The problem in my assignment is to verify the length of a string(a phone number in this case) given in a form that is POSTed, and then create a substring consisting of a portion of the data given. 
 Specifically if the number is 6235551234, the selection should be 555.

```
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

if (strlen($phone) = 10) {
        $phone_prefix = substr($phone, 3, 3);
    } else {
        echo 'Enter Proper phone number' ;
    }
```

However for the code I receive this error.. "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context
 Any ideas?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You try to assign value to function return

```
if (strlen($phone) = 10) {
```

You should have:

```
if (strlen($phone) == 10) {
```